# Looking for help on how to add math equation into my query

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to retrieve 'Tickets' from Tickets_Sold under some conditions:

- Tickets whose cost less than 15 even after adding 5.5% to the cost
- The ticket_type can be 1 or 4
- The Ticket is not 'VIP" i.e VIP equal to 'VIP'

I have

```
SELECT Tickets 
FROM Tickets_sold
WHERE Tickets < 15+(Ticket*0.055) 
AND Ticket_type 1 OR 4 and Ticket NOT LIKE 'VIP';
```

anyone see any problems with this?

Comment: so basically your trying to `SELECT` ticket less than `15`.

Comment: A few things I am suspicious of, Ticket NOT LIKE 'N'? should this be Ticket NOT LIKE 'VIP',  WHERE Tickets <  - but the calculation is on ticket also the comparison is wrong  should perhaps be where ticket+(Ticket*0.055) < 15. Please add your table definition and sample data as text to the question.

Comment: Salmon I think you helped me with my issue, my math equation is set up incorrectly. From what you said it should be -- WHERE Tickets+(Tickets*0.055) < 15. This would give me the correct answer. Since they are asking for the ticket cost EVEN AFTER adding 5.5%.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Is there a `cost` column?  Why doesn't the sample query use it?

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with each of your 3 conditions:

> `Tickets < 15 + (Ticket * 0.055)`

As commented by P.Salmon, you actually want: `Tickets + (Tickets * 0.055) < 15`

> `Ticket_type 1 OR 4`

That's a syntax error. You want types 1 and 4, so: `Ticket_type IN (1, 4)`

> `Ticket NOT LIKE 'N'`

This just checks if `ticket` is different than `'N'`. You want tickets other than `'VIP'`: `Ticket <> 'VIP'`

Here is a new version of your query:

```
SELECT Tickets 
FROM Tickets_sold
WHERE Tickets + (Tickets * 0.055) < 15 AND Ticket_type IN (1, 4) AND Ticket <> 'VIP'
```

Side note: having columns `Ticket` and `Tickets` in the same table is error-prone. You should give unambiguous, explicit names to your columns.